# Passing command line argument to subprocess module

Tags: python, perl, subprocess, popen

I have a Python script which calls Perl script using `subprocess` module. In terminal I run the Perl script like this:

```
perl email.pl raj@gmail.com
```

I am passing in "raj@email.com" as command line argument to that script. This is my Python script:

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl","./email.pl"])
print pipe
```

This works fine. But if I pass arguments it throws file not found:

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl","./email.pl moun"])
print pipe
```

Error:

```
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7ff7854d6550>
Can't open perl script "./email.pl moun": No such file or directory
```

How can I pass command line arguments in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command can be a string:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen("perl ./email.pl moun")
```

or a list:

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./email.pl", "moun"])
```

When it is a list, Python will escape special chars. So when you say

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl","./email.pl moun"])
```

It calls

```
perl "./email.pl moun"
```

But the file "email.pl moun" doesn't exist.

Above is a rough explanation and only works in Windows. For more detail, see @ShadowRanger 's comment.

Comment: The solution (second block of code) is correct, but the explanation is only loosely applicable to Windows systems, and wrong everywhere else. On non-Windows systems, Python isn't escaping a thing in the `list` based invocation (it's converting to a C level array of C-style strings and passing it directly to an `execvp` system call after `fork`). The first block of code isn't legal without passing `shell=True` on non-Windows systems. Even on Windows systems, the `list` based invocation is usually safer, because Python is better at handling the necessary escaping to produce the command string.